# Terminating Thread.Sleep() when another Thread terminates?

Tags: java, multithreading

I keep getting an interrupt from a thread within a thread and it won't let me destroy the main thread because of it. I would still like to use Thread.sleep() to slow down the loop.

**Main Thread:**

```
startEngine.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> {

        executor.submit(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                    lifeInstance.runEngine();
                }

            }

        });

    });

stopEngine.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> {
        executor.shutdownNow();
    });
```

**executor.submit is calling lifeInstance.runEngine() which is:**

```
public void runEngine() {

    //logic...

    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(LifeEngine.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

        return;
    }
}
```

**ERRROR:**

//Prints out stuff from runEngine()

```
Nov 06, 2016 6:04:52 PM thecell.LifeEngine runEngine
SEVERE: null
java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at thecell.LifeEngine.runEngine(LifeEngine.java:66)
    at UIControls.RightControls$1.run(RightControls.java:48)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

//Keeps printing out stuff from runEngine()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `isInterrupted()` returns `false`, when the `runEngine()` method returns on the `InterruptedException`.

From the book "Java Concurrency in Practice":

> Blocking library methods like `Thread.sleep` and `Object.wait` try to detect
>   when a thread has been interrupted and return early. They respond to interruption by **clearing the interrupted status and throwing InterruptedException**,
>   indicating that the blocking operation completed early due to interruption.

The interrupted state is cleared when you get the exception. You can reset it before return:

```
} catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(LifeEngine.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    return;
}
```

Actually, you *should* do this because your task code is executed by a thread pool, and it's good behaviour to preserve the interrupted state after your task code has processed it. So that the thread pool can respond to the interruption as well.